# How to Profile R Code that Includes SNOW Cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I have a nested loop that I'm using foreach, DoSNOW, and a SNOW socket cluster to solve for. How should I go about profiling the code to make sure I'm not doing something grossly inefficient.

Also is there anyway to measure the data flows going between the master and nodes in a Snow cluster?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an excellent question.  From the top of my head, start with a comparison between

- a serial solution (no snow),
- a serial solution with snow (to get an idea of overhead) and
- a parallel solution maybe controlling N to see what type of increase you get.

The never-released-on-CRAN version 0.3.4 of [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/package=snow) also has additional plotting commands that are useful for analysis.  You can get it from [this directory at Luke Tierney's site](http://www.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/R/cluster/).

Real profiling, of course, is *hard* given the distributed nature.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip.  I tried the increase controlling for N and got a fairly linear increase (since the problem I'm working on is essentially a resampling problem and hence pretty parrallelizable).

Is there a way to measure the dataflow between nodes? I get a feeling this is the bottleneck.

Comment: Not with R, I fear, but I could be missing something.  You could try standard networking tools.